# Interactions between pseudoline arrangements and braid groups?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, knot-theory, braid-groups, hyperplane-arrangements

It is common to represent 
[pseudoline arrangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_lines#Non-Euclidean_line_arrangements)
as wiring diagrams:

---

[image: Wiring]

          

<sup>Fig. from: "Hamiltonicity and colorings of arrangement graphs." *DAM* 154:17 (2006): 2470-2483.</sup>

---

Each pair of pseudolines cross exactly once.
It has become important in discrete and computational geometry to
generalize to curves which pairwise cross at most a constant $s$ times,
e.g.,

> Fox, Jacob, János Pach, and Csaba D. Tóth. "Intersection patterns of curves." *Journal of the London Mathematical Society* 83, no. 2 (2011): 389-406.
>   ([PDF download](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/paper-foxpachto.pdf).)

I wonder if the wiring diagrams of curves that cross at most $s$ times
can inherit useful properties from the extensive study of
[braid groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group)?
It seems, through superficial searching, that the two topics are largely disjoint, despite the evident visual similarities.

---

[image: Braids]

          

<sup>Image from [Ester Dalvit, Italian braids group](http://matematita.science.unitn.it/braids/summary.html).</sup>


          

<sup>Note: curve $4$ crosses $3$ twice, so this is not a pseudoline arrangement.</sup>

---

> ***Q***. Are there substantive interactions between the theory of braids and
>   the theory of curve arrangements?
>   If not, why not?

If one views a pseudoline arrangement $\sigma$ as an element of a braid group,
$\sigma^2$ is the identity, for as illustrated in the example above, 
$\sigma$ maps $(1,2,3,4,5)$ to $(5,4,3,2,1)$.

Comment: I see two problems: 1. Crossings in braids require a specification of an arc passing over the other one. Of course, you could declare that all arcs going South-East pass over the ones going SW, but then $\sigma^2$ is not the identity. 2. The third Reidemeister move $b_ib_{i+1}b_i=b_{i+1}b_ib_{i+1}$ changes the arrangement of crossings and, hence, the pseudoline arrangement, even though it does not change the braid.